# Fibonacci sequence recursion space complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, space-complexity

```
public int fib(int n) {
if (n == 0) return 0; 
if (n == 1) return 1; 
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

I am confused why the space complexity of the above code is O(n). 
Now, I know the depth of recursion is `n`, that is, the height of the tree.

There are no temporary variables or final result variables created. Is the space complexity here computed from the function call stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the space complexity in this case depends on the space used in call stack, that depends on the number of active function call (function called but not finished execution).

If you observe the last statement

```
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

When `fib(n-1)` is calculated `O(n)` space is used. Once `fib(n-1)` completes execution stack space can be reused by `fib(n-2)`.

So, in this case, the number of active stack frame at any time for a call to `fib(n)` is `O(n)`, hence the space complexity is `O(n)`.

It is worth noting that the time complexity, however, is exponential.